# Pause and Resume "Line" growth animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation

[image: The animation I need to implement. Please help me.]

I have tried so many ways but could not do it smoothly, I am a kind a newB in animations any help would be appreciated.

Code I Tried:

I have the buttons and the labels in need to add in two arrays. eventBtnsPopUpArray and eventLabelsPopUpArray. I try to add them in a loop and the animation is not smooth.

```
if ([eventBtnsPopUpArray count]>0)
{           

    CABasicAnimation* scalingAnimation;
    scalingAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame.size"];;
    scalingAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    scalingAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1024];
    scalingAnimation.duration = 5.0;
    scalingAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    scalingAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    scalingAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [calendarEventView.layer addAnimation:scalingAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];


  for (int k=0; k<[eventBtnsPopUpArray count]; k++)
{
    UIButton *btn = [eventBtnsPopUpArray objectAtIndex:0];
    UILabel *lbl = [eventLabelsPopUpArray objectAtIndex:0];



    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         [self addSubview:btn];
                         [self addSubview:lbl];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self pauseLayer:calendarEventView.layer];

                         [self resumeLayer:calendarEventView.layer];
                     }
     ];


}


if (calendarEventView.frame.size.width < 1024) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"DrawLineTillEnd" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    calendarEventView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 65, 1024, 7);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```

//Pause and resume layer functions

```
    -(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
    {
     CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
     layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
    }  

    -(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
    {
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = 
    [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime()  fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use core-animation, just use an NSTimer and adjust the frame (width) of the UIView using a changing variable... A simple conditional statement (if-statement) checking the width can stop it at a certain point and add the first desired UIButton. When clicked this button will change a BOOLEAN which will trigger the code in the NSTimer to continue line-growth until it reaches the next width defined by the next if-statement. etc.

Comment: Thanks albert, but the button click wont trigger the line-growth, button will just be added with a zoom or easeIn animation may be for one second. Then the line growth starts.

Comment: I don't understand, are you using an NSTimer and changing the width of a `UIView`? When the button appears set a BOOLEAN to "NO" (or 0) and then use a conditional statement in your animation which halts animation unless that BOOLEAN is set to "YES" (or 1)... For the IBAction of the UIButton cause it to change the BOOLEAN value to YES (or 1) on the `touchUpInside` event.

Comment: There will not be any interaction with the buttons and I am not using NSTimer. All of this should happen automatically (when the page loads -viewDidLoad()).

Comment: Ah, so you want it to pause, add the button, then start going again without the user having to click anything!

Comment: You should still be able to do this with an NSTimer... just set an `int` variable to 0 and increase it by 1 for every time-interval that passes... let's say you want the pause to be for 2 seconds and your NSTimer has a time-interval of 0.1, then when this variable == 20 ... ( aka 2seconds / 0.1f) you can set the BOOLEAN to 1 (YES) which will resume animation.

Comment: Yes exactly thats what i want.

Comment: (*Note, you don't have to use an NSTimer if you can detect the end of your animation.... you could just use a `preformSelector` event with an `AfterDelay:` parameter.)

Comment: Good luck, I'm going to bed, it's 2am here! God bless!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you can do this using coreplot or coreanimation but doing this is really simple by view animation

for example

```
-(void)animateLine{
   UILabel *labelObj = [[UiLabel alloc]init];
   //Set background image and height of label say 100 pixel
   for(int incrementer = 0; incrementer<100; incrementer ++)
    {
         [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
         [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.01];
         [labelObj setFrame:cgRectMake(0,100,incrementer,20)];
         [uiview commitAnimation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav , i have done somthing similar but i want the animation to pause at some point do another animation then start growing, i mean resume the line animation.

Comment: No the above code will not pause the animation, I guess there has to be two animations running each semaphoring the other.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code above will cause it to stop after it reaches a certain width... at that point you can add your button, have some sort of timer or delay take place and then resume animation by changing the width variable (incrementer) to the next desired growth width (say 200)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw : you can call this method from drawrect method with increment value. in that case it will work according to your needs. You can pass 0.01 for slight increment and 0 for no increment at all

Comment: @amar, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw : drawrect is a very expensive functions which is called continuously

Comment: @iVaibhav , well a suggestion to our questioner than, create the UIView with the desired width and move it off screen, then just translate the object from off-screen to on-screen which will simulate growth from the left side of the screen to any given point away from the left side without being greedy with memory. (*Since in his example he said it starts w/ frame (0,0,0,0)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw : translating it or expanding it will consume same amount of memory. I can suggest you even better way.

Comment: @iVaibhav ,  Less memory than just translating? I'd be very happy to learn :)

Comment: use this method `-(void )animateLinefromPoint:(int)previousEndingPoint toEndingPoint:(int)endPoint {
   UILabel *labelObj = [[UiLabel alloc]init];
 int width = endPoint - previousEndingPoint;
   for(int incrementer = 0; incrementer < width; incrementer ++)
   {
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.01];
       [labelObj setFrame:cgRectMake(0,100,previousEndingPoint + incrementer,20)];
       [uiview commitAnimation];
    }
}`

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw  translating frame does not take care of sub views buddy you have to take care of it mannually...which i hate any ways ur choice..where as trasform is applied to all subviews by default